# News Article Data

Tags: data-request, economics, politics, news

I'm looking to find historical news articles (Politics/ Economics especially, eg. CNN, Bloomberg) from the past several years. The articles would need to have time stamps and be downloadable as an archive so that they can be used in a machine learning algorithm. Any ideas where to find such data?

Comment: Your answer is maybe already among the other [news questions](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+news) on this site. Not exactly duplicates, but many sources in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wayback machine [archive.org](https://Archive.org) has coverage for news sites, e.g. CNN.

It can be bulk downloaded, see e.g. [here](https://blog.archive.org/2012/04/26/downloading-in-bulk-using-wget/), which discusses using wget.

Answer (score 0):

Some large news datasets available here: https://www.kaggle.com/therohk/datasets