# How to get old top news?

Tags: machine-learning, news

I am not sure this is the right forum to ask.

For a machine learning training, I need a dataset of old top news by keywords that can be organized by date. From where I can download it? I have seen that Google News API can provide only real time news.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [News Article Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/news-article-data)